# Hack an actionscript password field?

Tags: flash, actionscript, passwords, actionscript-2

I have this simple actionscript 2.0 code for a password field.. you have to enter "hello" to get the string "yes" otherwise you get the string "no" returned.. I was wondering if there were any flash terms you could enter into the input text field to still get access other than "hello"

i.e. entering passwordstring would make the if statement say (read the code at the bottom first)...

```
if(passwordstring == passwordstring)
```

but that doesn't work..

here is my code:

```
passwordstring = "hello"

_root.onEnterFrame = function()
{
    if(textfield.text == passwordstring)
    {
        trace("yes");
    }
    else
    {
        trace("no");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(passwordstring == passwordstring)
```

This line will try match a **property** `passwordstring` against another **property** `passwordstring`. Entering `"passwordstring"` into the text-field will not be the same as this, as it would read `if("passwordstring" == passwordstring)` which would evaluate to `false`.

For example this would evaluate to `false`:

```
var value:String = "abc";
trace("value" == value); // false
```

Comment: This is correct. @Albert This is the difference between a literal string and the reference (or pointer) to a string.

Comment: Yes, I understand this.. I'm wondering if there is anything other than "abc" you can use to have it return "true"... That's why I'm asking about a "hack" of somesort... something you can enter into the string that would confuse the actionscript and return "true" even though it is not "abc"?

Comment: Nope.. If you're trying to match against a string value then only that exact string value will allow your if() to evaluate to true.

Comment: I tried entering for the password.... something" || password != "something
` `
` `This way the if statement would read... if (password == "something" || password != "something") { .... but it still didn't work /:

Comment: This old questions just popped up in my notifications; wow almost 6 years! To clarify I was talking about potential injection attacks, similar to SQL Injection, but for ActionScript. My terminology is a little better now haha

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simply use a normal textfield but use `pwd_txt.displayAsPassword = true;`

Here is an another example also,
http://marianomike.com/2009/03/18/easy-flash-as3-password-validation/